# Inline Javascript is executing even when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, chromium, will-paginate

I have used a javascript function to ping server again and again.

```
function server_ping(url, time_limit){
    if(time_limit == undefined) time_limit = 3000;
    $.get(url);
    setTimeout(function(){server_ping(url);}, time_limit);
}
```

Although I have applied some work around, but this solution looks more like a hack.

```
var ping_timeout;

// clearing ping time out
if (ping_timeout != undefined){
    clearTimeout(ping_timeout);
}
function server_ping(url, time_limit){
    if(time_limit == undefined) time_limit = 3000;
    $.get(url);
    ping_timeout = setTimeout(function(){server_ping(url);}, time_limit);
}
```

Also I have pagination on my page, so when I am clicking next page, there are two requests now in the interval of 3 seconds. Also in my network console of chrome I noticed that page is not loading fully. 
Is there some problem in browser, or I am missing something.

Also I have coded my application in rails and using gem will paginate for pagination.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what is your problem exactly. *Is there some problem in browser* - some 99,999% not.

Comment: You may be calling the `server_ping` function by accident when you are paginating. I honestly am not sure as there is just not enough info here to draw any reasonable conclusion. Is it possible you could dump it all on a fiddle or is there a link we could check out?